Error writing to file when using TeamCity Docker Build
I am currently trying to build my DockerImage in TeamCity. At the moment it says build failed, Could not write lines to file "obj\Release\net6.0\XXX.Api.Rest.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt". Access to the path when I googled, there's this post Dotnet build "Access to the path is denied"; windows container docker build on Teamcity agent but unfortunately this is not an ideal solution.
May I ask how do I get permissions to be properly granted so I can build my docker image.
